# Error for HttpResponseCode cannot be resolved to a type while checking URL status code for links

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, httpurlconnection

I wrote simple program for checking URL status code. But eclipse giving me error saying HttpResponseCode cannot be resolved to a type. What should I do.

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class StarWarSocialMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        String sDriverPath = "C:\\BrowserDriver\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", sDriverPath);
        int statusCode;
        final String URL = "https://www.starwars.com/";
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        List<WebElement> socialMenu = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-external-links']//a")); 

        //System.out.println("Total Amenities "  + socialMenu.size());
        for (WebElement e : socialMenu)
        {
            //System.out.println(e.getAttribute("href"));
            String href = e.getAttribute("href");
            statusCode = new HttpResponseCode().httpResponseCodeViaGet(href);

            if(200 != statusCode) {
                System.out.println(href + " gave a response code of " + statusCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do? if jar files need to download then from where I can download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [How to get Response Status Code with Selenium WebDriver](https://www.testingexcellence.com/how-to-get-response-status-code-with-selenium-webdriver/) in Selenium WebDriver there is no direct method to check the response status code, so we have to use another library. You can use [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) or [REST-assured library from Jayway](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured).

### httpResponseCodeViaGet()

To use the method `httpResponseCodeViaGet()` you have to download and use the following import:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
```

And then you can use:

```
new HttpResponseCode().httpResponseCodeViaGet("http://www.google.com");
```

### Solution

As an alternative you can use *HttpURLConnection* and `openConnection()` and you can use the following solution:

```
package demo;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class BrokenLinks {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String sDriverPath = "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", sDriverPath);
        String statusCode;
        final String URL = "https://www.starwars.com/";
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        List<WebElement> socialMenu = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-external-links']//a")); 
        System.out.println("Total Amenities "  + socialMenu.size());
        for (WebElement e : socialMenu)
        {
            String href = e.getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println(e.getAttribute("href"));
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(href).openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            statusCode = connection.getResponseMessage();
            connection.disconnect();
            if(!statusCode.contains("200")) {
                System.out.println(href + " gave a response code of " + statusCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```