# Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol error while finding broken links in a page using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, httpurlconnection

I am trying to find the broken link in a page through Selenium(Java) code but I am facing this issue. I am not able to run this code due to the below exception. In this code, the total number of links in a page is found then the URL of links is found. Please see the issue and give me the resolution for this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at fire.Weil.main(Weil.java:57)
```

My code is: -

```
package fire;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Weil {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\sumitk\\Downloads\\Selenium Drivers\\Gecodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //delete all cookies
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        //dynamic wait
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //open site
        driver.get("https://www.weil.com/");

        //1. get the list of all the links and images
        List<WebElement> linklist = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        linklist.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("img")));

        System.out.println("Size of full links and images--->"+ linklist.size());

        List<WebElement> activeLinks =new ArrayList<WebElement>();

        // 2. iterate linklist : exclude all the links/images does not have any href attribute
        for(int i=0; i<linklist.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(linklist.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            if(linklist.get(i).getAttribute("href") !=null)
            {
                activeLinks.add(linklist.get(i));
            }
        }

        //get the size of active links list.
        System.out.println("Size of active links and images--->"+ activeLinks.size());

        //3. check the href url, with httpconnection api.
        for(int j=0; j<activeLinks.size(); j++)
        {
            HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) new URL(activeLinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")).openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            String response=connection.getResponseMessage();
            connection.disconnect();
            System.out.println(activeLinks.get(j).getAttribute("href") +" --->"+response);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line is `Weil.java:57`

Comment: `Url` must be absolut and i think `activeLinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")` only returns a relative Url

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
```

...implies that your program was trying to access an `URL` which doesn't have a protocol i.e. `HTTP` or `HTTPS` is absent.

Your logic was near perfect. A few words:

- It may be possible that some of the `<a>` elements within the webpage https://www.weil.com/ have `href` attribute have no value assigned. As an example:

  - `<a class="canvas-button ss-icon" href="">?</a>`
  - `<a class="search-button ss-icon" href="">Search</a>`
- That is the reason this line:

  ```
  System.out.println("Size of active links and images--->"+ activeLinks.size());
  //prints: Size of active links and images--->72
  ```
- But if you print the `href` attribute:

  ```
  for(int i=0; i<activeLinks.size(); i++)
      System.out.println(activeLinks.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
  ```
- The first two lines are blank as follows:

  ```
  <blank>
  <blank>
  https://www.weil.com/
  https://www.weil.com/
  https://www.weil.com/people
  ```
- I made a couple of simple tweaks in your code as follows:

  - Replaced `findElements(By.tagName("a"))` with `findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains (@href, 'weil')]"))`
  - Replaced `findElements(By.tagName("img"))` with `findElements(By.xpath("//img[contains (@src, 'weil')]"))`
- Here is the execution result:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    public class A_Chrome_Demo {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("start-maximized");
                options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
                options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
                WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
                driver.get("https://www.weil.com/");
                List<WebElement> linklist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains (@href, 'weil')]"));
                linklist.addAll(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[contains (@src, 'weil')]")));
                System.out.println("Size of full links and images--->"+ linklist.size());
                List<WebElement> activeLinks =new ArrayList<WebElement>();
                for(int i=0; i<linklist.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(linklist.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
                    if(linklist.get(i).getAttribute("href") !=null)
                        activeLinks.add(linklist.get(i));
                }
                System.out.println("Size of active links and images--->"+ activeLinks.size());
                for(int j=0; j<activeLinks.size(); j++)
                {
                    HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) new URL(activeLinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")).openConnection();
                    connection.connect();
                    String response=connection.getResponseMessage();
                    connection.disconnect();
                    System.out.println(activeLinks.get(j).getAttribute("href") +" --->"+response);
                }
            }
    }
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    Size of full links and images--->46
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil
    https://extranet.weil.com/
    https://login.weil.com/
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-elects-16-new-partners-and-announces-new-counsel-class-2019
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-announces-weil-legal-innovators-program
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-partners-receive-top-honors-in-2019
    https://www.weil.com/articles/two-weil-partners-named-among-turnarounds-workouts-outstanding-restructuring-lawyers-for-2019
    https://careers.weil.com/
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-wins-five-2019-law360-practice-group-of-the-year-awards
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-earns-2020-litigation-department-of-the-year-honorable-mention-from-the-american-lawyer
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-leads-three-of-the-five-top-bankruptcy-cases-of-2019
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/about-weil-prominent-matters
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-represented-french-state-in-landmark-privatization-and-ipo-of-francaise-des-jeux
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-litigators-clinch-four-win-week-showcasing-cross-departmental-strengths
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-advised-guggenheim-securities-and-morgan-stanley-on-jack-in-the-boxs-1-3b-securitization
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/not-for-profit
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-secures-asylum-for-burkina-faso-native-escaping-persecution
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weils-2019-pro-bono-annual-review-our-finest-hours
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-and-nysba-task-force-deliver-report-on-wrongful-convictions-in-new-york-state
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/diversity-and-inclusion
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-named-a-2020-best-place-to-work-for-lgbtq-equality
    https://www.weil.com/articles/three-weil-partners-named-best-practitioners-in-their-fields
    http://business-finance-restructuring.weil.com/
    http://eurorestructuring.weil.com/
    http://privateequity.weil.com/
    http://governance.weil.com/
    http://product-liability.weil.com/
    https://tax.weil.com/
    https://tax.weil.com/
    https://tax.weil.com/
    https://tax.weil.com/
    https://tax.weil.com/
    https://tax.weil.com/
    https://tax.weil.com/
    https://tax.weil.com/latest-thinking/cryptoassets-hmrc-uk-tax-net-widens/
    http://business-finance-restructuring.weil.com/automatic-stay/denial-of-stay-relief-is-a-final-order-says-the-u-s-supreme-court/
    http://business-finance-restructuring.weil.com/news/weil-wins-five-2019-law360-practice-group-of-the-year-awards/
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/green-policy
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/sitemap
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/privacy-policy
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/privacy-shield-notice
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/regulatory-information
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/disclaimer
    null
    null
    null
    Size of active links and images--->43
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil --->OK
    https://extranet.weil.com/ --->OK
    https://login.weil.com/ --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-elects-16-new-partners-and-announces-new-counsel-class-2019 --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-announces-weil-legal-innovators-program --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-partners-receive-top-honors-in-2019 --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/two-weil-partners-named-among-turnarounds-workouts-outstanding-restructuring-lawyers-for-2019 --->OK
    https://careers.weil.com/ --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-wins-five-2019-law360-practice-group-of-the-year-awards --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-earns-2020-litigation-department-of-the-year-honorable-mention-from-the-american-lawyer --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-leads-three-of-the-five-top-bankruptcy-cases-of-2019 --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/about-weil-prominent-matters --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-represented-french-state-in-landmark-privatization-and-ipo-of-francaise-des-jeux --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-litigators-clinch-four-win-week-showcasing-cross-departmental-strengths --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-advised-guggenheim-securities-and-morgan-stanley-on-jack-in-the-boxs-1-3b-securitization --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/not-for-profit --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-secures-asylum-for-burkina-faso-native-escaping-persecution --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weils-2019-pro-bono-annual-review-our-finest-hours --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-and-nysba-task-force-deliver-report-on-wrongful-convictions-in-new-york-state --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/diversity-and-inclusion --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/weil-named-a-2020-best-place-to-work-for-lgbtq-equality --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/articles/three-weil-partners-named-best-practitioners-in-their-fields --->OK
    http://business-finance-restructuring.weil.com/ --->Forbidden
    http://eurorestructuring.weil.com/ --->Forbidden
    http://privateequity.weil.com/ --->Forbidden
    http://governance.weil.com/ --->Forbidden
    http://product-liability.weil.com/ --->Forbidden
    https://tax.weil.com/ --->Forbidden
    https://tax.weil.com/ --->Forbidden
    https://tax.weil.com/ --->Forbidden
    https://tax.weil.com/ --->Forbidden
    https://tax.weil.com/ --->Forbidden
    https://tax.weil.com/ --->Forbidden
    https://tax.weil.com/ --->Forbidden
    https://tax.weil.com/latest-thinking/cryptoassets-hmrc-uk-tax-net-widens/ --->Forbidden
    http://business-finance-restructuring.weil.com/automatic-stay/denial-of-stay-relief-is-a-final-order-says-the-u-s-supreme-court/ --->Forbidden
    http://business-finance-restructuring.weil.com/news/weil-wins-five-2019-law360-practice-group-of-the-year-awards/ --->Forbidden
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/green-policy --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/sitemap --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/privacy-policy --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/privacy-shield-notice --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/regulatory-information --->OK
    https://www.weil.com/about-weil/disclaimer --->OK
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Error for HttpResponseCode cannot be resolved to a type while checking URL status code for links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599407/error-for-httpresponsecode-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-while-checking-url-statu/54608205#54608205)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Web Page contains 'a' Tag Elements with no reference to the href keyword.

i.e. Top Left-most List-Drawer Icon and Search Icon.

Refer the attached image.

[image]

Using a try catch block for java.net.MalformedURLException could possibly help you out and would allow you to move ahead with the desired flow.

[image]